# Is there a way to keep full margins in ggplot2 pdf output?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017301/2554330 I partially answered a problem in resizing subfigures in `ggplot2` output using code similar to this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{subcaption}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.height=3, fig.width=1,fig.subcap=c("first", "second", "third"),fig.cap="Main"}
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(30),
  y = rnorm(30)
)
p1 <- p2 <- p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p1 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,0),"in") + theme_get()$plot.margin)
p2 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1/2,0,1/2,0),"in") + theme_get()$plot.margin)
p3
```
````

This produces this output:

[image: screenshot]

Notice how there is no bottom margin in the first and second plots, even though I requested equal top and bottom margins.  If I look at the actual `.pdf` files in the figure directory, I can see that they don't contain any margins at all:  the file seems to have been cropped to the edge of the bounding box of the ink on the page, so the first plot is (according to Acrobat "Document Properties")
0.83in by 0.83in, the second is 0.83in by 1.83in, and the last one is 0.83in by 2.83in.

What I'd expect to get is to have each of the three plots vertically centred within the 1in by 3in size that I requested.  The PDF files should all be that size.

Is there a way to suppress this cropping?

Comment: sorry, it's a bit unclear what you want to get - want to get the plots aligned in some way? Maybe best and safest to create a combined plot *first*, with `cowplot`or `patchwork`, then knitting it.

Comment: @Tjebo, I've added some text to explain what I want.  I don't want a combined plot, because I want to use LaTeX subfigure environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the `knitr` and `rmarkdown` source code for a while, I've found the answer.  The `rmarkdown::pdf_document` output function has an argument `fig_crop` that defaults to `TRUE`.  Setting it to `FALSE` suppresses cropping of figures in the whole document.  So all I need to do in this example is change my header YAML to include

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_crop: FALSE
```

and the problem is solved.  As far as I know there is no chunk-level option to change this:  all figures are cropped, or none are.

Comment: Was coming across a very similar problem and thinking back to this here. only now found this related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195871/adjusting-figure-margins-in-rmarkdown